# Two select query from two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to join two **select** statements into one. How do look like query to combine two results?

```
SELECT Name FROM students WHERE No = 4
SELECT TOP 1 pchar FROM pcharacter ORDER BY NEWID();
```

I tried this;

```
SELECT TOP 1 students.Name, pcharacter.pchar
FROM students, pcharacter
WHERE No = 4
ORDER BY NEWID();
```

Is this the proper way or not? I get desired result.

Comment: Please show sample data and desired results.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Seems highly unlikely to be the proper way since you don't have a join condition, in fact your join should be upgraded to a proper join rather than an implicit join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query results are tables again, so you can join them just like you join stored tables. For instance:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT Name FROM students WHERE No = 4) query1
CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT TOP 1 pchar FROM pcharacter ORDER BY NEWID()) query2
;
```

As to your own query: The query is quite okay. You select one student and join it with all characters and then pick one of the resulting rows randomly. It would be better of course to pick one random character first and only then join with the student. Just as you have said: Join the two queries. And as Dale K has rightly pointed out in the request comments: comma-separated joins got replaced by proper joins (INNER JOIN, LEFT OUTER JOIN etc.) in 1992. You should not use that ancient syntax anymore.

Answer (score 2):

It appears you're attempting to associate a random row from the pcharacter table with each row from the students table WHERE No=4.  As such CROSS APPLY seems appropriate

```
SELECT s.[Name], pc.pchar
FROM students s
     cross apply (select top 1 pchar
                  from pcharacter
                  order by newid()) pc
WHERE s.[No]=4;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a union query:

```sql
SELECT Name FROM students WHERE No = 4
UNION ALL
SELECT pchar
FROM (SELECT TOP 1 pchar FROM pcharacter ORDER BY NEWID()) t;
```

This assumes that both the `Name` and `pchar` columns are text, i.e. they have the same type.  If not, then we might need some casting to make the above work.

Comment: I got an error message, “ORDER BY item must appear in the select list if the statement contains a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator.

Comment: @nebo Sorry, careless error, it has been corrected.